# How to add BlueMix Monitoring and Analytics to a docker-hosted app?

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud, analytics, monitoring

Our app (Meteor/NodeJS) is deployed in a docker container in Bluemix, and I'd like to add the Monitoring and Analytics service to the app. The documentation lists how to integrate it with a NodeJS app deployed directly to Bluemix, and also mentions how to integrate with a Ruby-based app. Seems like there should just be an npm package to install, but I see nothing in the docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Monitoring and Analytics Service is only for Cloud Foundry based Application in IBM Bluemix based on Java Liberty, Node.js SDK or Ruby. The buildpacks have additional configuration and components inside to enable integration with the M&A Service.
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/monana/index.html#monana_oview

For IBM Bluemix Container Service with Docker you need to use the built-in Monitoring and Logging for Containers
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2015/11/built-in-monitoring-and-logging-for-bluemix-containers/